# Does Javascript have a filter function with a time complexity of O(log n)?

Tags: javascript, performance, time-complexity

I want to filter an array of strings by the first k letters of each string. Like this:

```
stringArray.filter((stringVar)=>{
    return stringVar.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(someLetters); 
 });
```

Based on prior StackOverflow questions, my understanding is that the default filter function only works in O(n) time. However, since my array of strings is already sorted in alphabetical ordered, this task could theoretically be accomplished in O(log n) time. Is there any alternative Javascript function or library available that can accomplish this task in O(log n) time? Or would I have to design something from scratch to achieve O(log n) time?

Comment: You'd probably have to write your own. The tasks where a filter can work on a sorted array in `(O log(n))` are a miniscule amount compared to the general case. Consider `arr.filter(x => x % 2 === 1)` to get just the odd numbers. An array sorted in ascending/descending order will not help in this case.

Comment: Did you find that bottleneck within an actual implementation and with a specialized profiler? If not, then the question is not (yet) worth to be asked.